# How can you tell if one function is faster than another function according to O-notation?

Tags: performance, big-o

I have an issue with how to determine if 1 function is faster or slower than another function. If the professor uses an example of O(1) and O(n), I know O(1) is faster but I really only know that from memorizing the simple functions running time order... But if more complex examples are given, I don't understand how to find the faster function.

For example, let's say I want to compare n^logn and n^(logn)^2 and n^(sqrt(n)). How can I compare these functions and be able to tell which has a fastest and slowest running time (big-O notation)? Is there a step by step process that I can follow each time so that I can use when comparing functions running time?

Here's my thought about the above example. I know n^2 is faster than n^3. So I want to compare the n^____ of each function. So if I plug in n=1000000 in each, logn will have the smallest value, logn^2 will have the second, and logn^sqrt(n) will have the biggest. Does this mean that the smallest value (n^logn) will be the fastest and the biggest value (n^sqrt(n)) will be the slowest?
1. n^logn (fastest)
2. n^logn^2
3. n^sqrt(n) (slowest)

Comment: It depends on the value of N.  Look at a graph of the expressions.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. Complexity tells you about asymptotic behavior as `n` approaches infinity. It does not necessarily tell you about actual speed for any finite `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Big O is written as a function of N (except in case of constant, O(1)).

So it is simple a matter of plugging any N (3 or 4 values, or preferably enough values to see the curve) into both functions you are comparing and compute. Graph them if you can.

But you shouldn't need to do that, you should have a basic understanding for the classes of functions for Big O. If you can't calculate it, you should still know that O(log N) is larger than O(1), etc. O notation is about worst case. So usually the comparisons are easy if you are familiar with the most common functions.

> Does this mean that the smallest value (n^logn) will be the fastest
>   and the biggest value (n^sqrt(n)) will be the slowest? 1. n^logn
>   (fastest) 2. n^logn^2 3. n^sqrt(n) (slowest)

For the purpose of your comparison, yes. O notation is used to compare worst case, complexity, or class of algorithm, so you just assume worst case on all candidates in the comparison. You can't tell from O notation what the best, typical or average performance will be.

Comment: You also can't tell from O notation what will happen for any particular choice of n.  It's purely asymptotic, and it's important not to oversell it.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing O notations is basically the matter of comparing the curves. I recommend you to draw the curve - that will be helpful to your understanding.

If you use python, I'd like to recommend to try `mathplotlib.pyplot`. It's very convenient.